# How do you delete all the nodes on the right of a linked list when a value greater than 'x' is encountered?

Tags: singly-linked-list

I don't see solution to this specific question on stackoverflow. So I'm posting this.

My requirement is to delete all the nodes on the right of a linked list when a value greater than 'x' is encountered?
For Ex.

**Sample Input:**
Linked list has values: 5 1 2 6 and x = 5 
**Output:** 5 1 2

**Sample Input**
Linked list has values: 7 1 2 6 and x = 6 
**Output:** null (since 7 is greater than 6, it should delete all the nodes on the right)

**Sample Input:**
Linked list has values: 5 4 7 6 and x = 6
**Output:** 5 4

I came up with this solution, but I'm trying to find an optimal solution

```
//head is the root node, nodes greater that "value" should be deleted
      Node Delete(Node head, int value) {
      // Complete this method

       Node cur = head;
       Node prev = null;    

      if(cur == null)
           return head;

     if(cur != null && cur.data > value )
       {
         while(cur != null)
         {
          prev = cur;
          cur = cur.next;
         }
          prev.next = cur;
          head = prev;
          return head;
       }
      else
      {
         while(cur != null && cur.data <= value)
         {
          prev = cur;     
          cur = cur.next;    
         }  
         if(cur != null && cur.data > value)
         { 
           while(cur != null)
           {          
               cur = cur.next;        
           }
           prev.next = cur;    
           return head;
         }    
          prev.next = null;       
          return head;       
      }   


    }
```

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, the only solution I can think of is O(n). I see no need for an O(n^2) solution unless you're trying to do this Rube Goldberg-style.

Comment: Any Specific language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In language like Java which have garbage collection, it is as simple as to set the next of last element to `null` which in worst case will be of O(n) (which will happen when matched with last element)

```
Node deleteGreaterThan(Node head, int value){
   if(head==null || head.data>value)return null;//if head is itself greater than value
   Node temp = head;
   while(temp.next != null && temp.next.data<=value){
      temp= temp.next;
   }
   temp.next = null;
   return head;
}

head = deleteGreaterThan(head, 5);
```

I guess in language like c, you might have to explicitly delete each element and free the memory, no experience with c, so can't say much, even in that case it will only be O(n)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple O(n) solution in Javascript-style pseudocode,
with several identifiers renamed for clarity.

```js
function deleteGreater(head, value) {
    if (head == null) return null;
    if (head.data > value) {
        deallocate(head); //discard the entire list
        return null;
    }

    var current = head;

    while (true) {
        if (current.next == null) return head; //end of list
        if (current.next.data > value) break;
        current = current.next;
    }

    deallocate(current.next); //discard the rest of the list
    current.next = null; 
    return head;
}
```

I trust you can convert it to any language you want.

For languages with garbage collection, you can remove the `deallocate()` calls.
For languages without garbage collection, override the object's deallocation method to make sure that it also deallocates the `next` property.

Comment: This will only work for garbage collected languages.

Answer (score 1):

Like @100rabh said, in a language without garage collection you need to free every single node you allocated.  Here is an example in C of how to do that.  Notice that calling Delete is still O(n) because we actually update the previous node's next pointer while freeing the current node.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct _Node {
  struct _Node *next;
  int data;
};

typedef struct _Node Node;

Node* Build(int value)
{
  int i;
  Node *ptr, *head=NULL;

  for (i=1; i<value; i++)
  {
    if(head==NULL)
    {
      head=malloc(sizeof(Node));
      ptr=head;
    }
    else
    {
      ptr->next=malloc(sizeof(Node));
      ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->data=i;
    ptr->next=NULL;
    printf("Build: node=%p {data=%d next=%p}\n", ptr, ptr->data, ptr->next);
  }
  return head;
}

void Print(Node *head)
{
  Node *ptr=head;
  while(ptr!=NULL)
  {
    printf("Print: node=%p {data=%d, next=%p}\n", ptr, ptr->data, ptr->next);
    ptr=ptr->next;
  }
}

/*
 * We can't pass head or ptr->next directly
 * Because then we can't update it's value when we free what it points to
 * So we pass the pointer to head or ptr->next instead
 * Here we actually update head or ptr->next to point to the next node until we are finished
 */
void Free(Node **ptr)
{
  Node *temp;

  if(ptr==NULL) return;

  while(*ptr!=NULL)
  {
    temp=*ptr;
    *ptr=(*ptr)->next;

    printf("Free: node=%p {data=%d next=%p}\n",temp,temp->data,temp->next);
    temp->data=-temp->data;
    temp->next=NULL;
    free(temp);
  }
}

/*
 * We can't pass head or ptr->next directly
 * Because then we can't update it's value when we free what it points to
 * So we pass the pointer to head or ptr->next instead
 * Nothing gets updated in this function - Free does all the updating
 */
void Delete(Node **ptr, int value)
{
  if(ptr==NULL) return;

  while(*ptr!=NULL)
  {
    if((*ptr)->data>value)
    {
      printf("Delete: node=%p {data=%d node=%p}\n",*ptr,(*ptr)->data,(*ptr)->next);
      Free(ptr);
      return;
    }
    ptr=&(*ptr)->next;
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  Node *head=Build(10);
  Print(head);
  Delete(&head, 5);
  Print(head);
  Free(&head);
  return 0;
}
```